# Do nothing if the current symbol is not space

Tags: vimrc, normal-mode

I'm trying to configure line splitting which I want to make available only if the current symbol is space. I currently configured it as so:

```
r<ENTER>k$
```

But this does the following:

```
line1 line2
     ^
   cursor
```

to

```
line1
line2
```

and

```
line1line2
    ^
  cursor
```

to

```
line          <---------- 1 is missing
line2
```

which is not desirable. So I want to allow to split the line only if the current symbol is space. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an expression mapping:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>s getline('.')[col('.')-1] =~ "\\s" ? "r<Enter>k$" : ""
```

The `<expr>` will make Vim evaluate a Vimscript expression, instead of just a "static" list of keys.

Here, we use `getline('.')[col('.')-1]` to get the character under the cursor, we check if this is whitespace with `=~ "\\s"` (this will also match tabs etc.) and run `r<Enter>k$` if it is.

If it doesn't match, we do nothing.

---

Perhaps a more useful mapping is:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>q getline('.')[col('.')-1] =~ "\\s" ? "r<Enter>k$" : "i<Enter><Esc>k$"
```

Which will split the line without deleting whitespace.